# Combine Chart.js programmatic and legend based dataset toggling

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

How can I make programmatic toggling of datasets play together with the one from ChartJS' legend clicking?

Here's a repro of my problem:

1. Run below snippet.
2. Toggle fruit data off with button: just works!
3. Toggle fruit data back on with button: just works!
4. Toggle fruit off *by clicking the legend item*: works.
5. Toggle fruit back on *by clicking the legend item*: works.
6. Toggle fruit again with the *button*: ⚠ broken!

I expect the custom logic to play nice with ChartJS' built in feature.

```js
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    datasets: [
      { label: "Fruit", backgroundColor: "IndianRed", data: [1,2,3] },
      { label: "Veggies", backgroundColor: "LightGreen", data: [2,5,3] },
    ]
  }
 });
 
 function togglestuff() {
   const dataset = chart.data.datasets.find(ds => ds.label === "Fruit");
   dataset.hidden = !dataset.hidden;
   chart.update();
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
<div><canvas id="chart" height="75px"></canvas></div>
<button id="hide" onclick="togglestuff()">
  Toggle fruit programmatically
</button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `hidden` works, but there's also a property `visible` which then needs to be [programmatically used with `setDatasetVisibility(datasetIndex, visibility)`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/developers/api.html#setdatasetvisibility-datasetindex-visibility) .

So, one method would be:

1. Get dataset index with `indexOf` or similar
2. Get metadata at that index with `chart.getDatasetMeta(index)`
3. Use `metadata.visible` and pass it to `setDatasetVisibility(...)`
4. `chart.update()` as per usual

```js
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    datasets: [
      { label: "Fruit", backgroundColor: "IndianRed", data: [1,2,3] },
      { label: "Veggies", backgroundColor: "LightGreen", data: [2,5,3] },
    ]
  }
 });
 
 function togglestuff() {
   const dataset = chart.data.datasets.find(ds => ds.label === "Fruit");
   const index = chart.data.datasets.indexOf(dataset);
   const metadata = chart.getDatasetMeta(index);
   chart.setDatasetVisibility(
     index,
     !metadata.visible,
   );
   chart.update();
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
<div><canvas id="chart" height="75px"></canvas></div>
<button id="hide" onclick="togglestuff()">
  Toggle fruit programmatically
</button>
```